# second where name is not in scope of the previous where clause

Tags: haskell, scope, where-clause

I defined a where to define a name **earthSecondsAYear**. Sadly it does not manage to be in scope of the previous where clause.

Here is the code:

```
module SpaceAge (Planet(..), ageOn) where

data Planet = Mercury
            | Venus
            | Earth
            | Mars
            | Jupiter
            | Saturn
            | Uranus
            | Neptune

ageOn :: Planet -> Float -> Float
ageOn planet seconds = (seconds / 100) * planetYearSecs planet
 where planetYearSecs Mercury = (earthSecondsAYear / 100) * 0.2408
       planetYearSecs Venus = 0.6151
       planetYearSecs Mars = 1.8808
       planetYearSecs Jupiter = 11.8626
       planetYearSecs Saturn = 29.4474
       planetYearSecs Uranus = 84.0168
       planetYearSecs Neptune = 164.7913
       planetYearSecs Earth = 100
         where earthSecondsAYear = 31557600
```

Error message:

```
:14:34: error:
    Variable not in scope: earthSecondsAYear
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The `where` only applies to the definition immediately above it (so to `planetYearSecs Earth = 100`). This bites me all the time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `where` clause binds to a single pattern-match, and no wider. It *does* bind across multiple guard clauses, such as in:

```
foo :: Int -> Int
foo 0 = 0
foo x | y < 30 = 5
      | otherwise = y
  where y = x * x
```

Which may cause you to think it applies to a whole function definition. But you couldn't use `y` in the first equation here, just as you can't use `earthSecondsAYear` in the first equation of your question, because you have bound it to the last equation only.

However, the fix is easy: instead of introducing a new `where` clause, simply add another definition to your existing `where` clause:

```
ageOn :: Planet -> Float -> Float
ageOn planet seconds = (seconds / 100) * planetYearSecs planet
 where planetYearSecs Mercury = (earthSecondsAYear / 100) * 0.2408
       planetYearSecs Venus = 0.6151
       planetYearSecs Mars = 1.8808
       planetYearSecs Jupiter = 11.8626
       planetYearSecs Saturn = 29.4474
       planetYearSecs Uranus = 84.0168
       planetYearSecs Neptune = 164.7913
       planetYearSecs Earth = 100
       earthSecondsAYear = 31557600
```

It is perfectly legal to define multiple bindings in a `where` clause, just by indenting them all to the same level. And when you do, all definitions inside the where clause can see all the bound values, so your first equation will happily use the value defined in your last equation.